# Keras Model not learning using Model API

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am running following code to make keras model for classifaction and I can not figure out what is wrong as all the layers seem to be fine.The model is not learning

Dataset used: Cifar-10

Envoirment: Google colab

Code:

```
# Dataset Props
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
total_cats = 10

#Code for making model
inputs = Input(shape=(input_shape))

x1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2))(inputs)
x1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides=2, kernel_initializer = initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0, stddev=0.05, seed=None), name = 'conv_layer_1')(x1)
x1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(x1)

x2 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2))(x1)
x2 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides=2, kernel_initializer = initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0, stddev=0.05, seed=None),name = 'conv_layer_2')(x2)
x2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(x2)

x3 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2))(x2)
x3 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides=2, kernel_initializer = initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0, stddev=0.05, seed=None), name = 'conv_layer_3')(x3)
x3 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(x3)


x4 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2))(x3)
x4 = Conv2D(512, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides=2, kernel_initializer = initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0, stddev=0.05, seed=None), name = 'conv_layer_4')(x4)
x4 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(x4)

x4_f = Flatten()(x4)

x5 = Dense(2048, name='dense_layer_1')(x4_f)
x5 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(x5)

x6 = Dense(2048, name='dense_layer_2')(x5)
x6 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)(x6)

x8 = Dense(128, name='dense_layer_7')(x6)
x9 = Dense(total_cats, name='dense_layer_8', activation='softmax')(x8)

model = Model(inputs, output = x9)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6), metrics = ['accuracy'])

trained_model = model.fit(x_train[0:10000], y_train_hot[0:10000], epochs=5, batch_size=64)
```

Note:
I do not get any error(s) and the same architecture if made using Sequential works fine. Following is the output i am getting for above mentioned code

```
Epoch 1/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 11s 1ms/step - loss: 14.5506 - acc: 0.0972
Epoch 2/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 10s 980us/step - loss: 14.5482 - acc: 0.0974
Epoch 3/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 10s 980us/step - loss: 14.5482 - acc: 0.0974
Epoch 4/5
 1216/10000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 14.8191 - acc: 0.080610000/10000 [==============================] - 10s 985us/step - loss: 14.5482 - acc: 0.0974
Epoch 5/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 10s 983us/step - loss: 14.5482 - acc: 0.0974
```

Comment: Learning rate seem's to be too high, use 0.0001 and train it for at least 100 epochs before coming to a conclusion, hardly takes 15 minutes to train for 100 epochs.

Comment: Truncated normal doesn't seem to be a great initializer in my opinion... the more varying weights you have, the less stuck is your model. I'd leave the standard initializer.

Comment: Your model doesn't seem completely stuck though, as sometimes the loss may vary. It may be pushing too fast into the leaky relu's negative zone. Increasing the alpha, like, `0.01` may also help seeing a more variable loss. (Besides doing what Vikas suggested)

Comment: @VikasNS Thank you for response, I have tried changing learning rate to 0.0001, didn't create much difference.

Comment: @DanielMöller I have tried aplha = 0.01 for leakyrelu and changing initilization method to VarianceScaling, There is a  huge change after changing initilization method and now the model is learning quickly.

Thank you for this helpful suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the comments as an answer:

- Truncated normal doesn't seem to be a great initializer in my opinion... the more varying weights you have, the less stuck is your model. I'd leave the standard initializer.
- Your model doesn't seem completely stuck though, as sometimes the loss may vary. It may be pushing too fast into the leaky relu's negative zone. Increasing the alpha, like, 0.01 may also help seeing a more variable loss. (Besides doing what Vikas suggested: decrease the learning rate and training for way more epochs)